# phonegap cant install cordova camera

Tags: xcode, cordova

Hi I'm trying to write an IOS app with phonegap that uses the camera, i have all the code etc but I think i'm missing the camera plugin for xCode as its not in the plugins directory when i build the project.

i have tried installing the plugin using

```
phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

But keep getting this strange error?

```
Error: Unpublished by stevegill on 2015-01-30T00:59:15.025Z
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You can just install it with

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

but is requires cordova 5.0+

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the plugin doesn't work with iOS

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/

As you can see at the top, the iOS build is failing, so that may be why it has been unpublished.